# Does "angular cheilitis" have any more commonly used synonyms than "perlèche" or "rhagades" which regular people would recognize?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, technical, french, greek

The field of medical pathology uses the term [***angular cheilitis***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_cheilitis). I’m looking for a common word or phrase to use in place of this highly specialized technical term that I fear is likely to be known only by specialists.

It has several synonyms that are still too fancy for what I’m looking to use this for, including [*perlèche*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/perl%C3%A8che/59657) and [*rhagades*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/165109).   Is there any common term for this condition in English? My searches on Google were fruitless!

According to the [the OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/31205), *cheilitis* means:

> *Pathology.* Inflammation of the lip.

It’s composed of two scientific forms: the combining form [*cheil‑, cheilo‑*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/31203) from Greek *χειλο*- meaning lip, plus the suffix [*‑itis*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/100349) meaning inflammation.

[The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/angular+cheilitis) provides more details about this scientific term:

> a disorder of the lips marked by scaling and fissures at the corners of the mouth; caused by a deficiency of riboflavin

What do regular people call this in English?

Comment: [What is angular cheilitis?](https://www.dermnetnz.org/topics/angular-cheilitis/) *...also called **angular stomatitis, cheilosis** and **perleche** (perlèche).*

Comment: @FumbleFingers But are they common words in English? I mean, are they something like "mouth ulcer" or "canker sore" for "Aphthous stomatitis"?

Comment: It looks like the answer may well be 'No'. Have you tried medical sites, BM? There's a Medical Sciences SE, for instance.

Comment: I never knew there was such a thing – I certainly don’t know a word for it (or didn’t, until now).

Comment: @BeatsMe I noticed that you were already linking to *perlèche* so I figure that’s still not the common term you’re looking for. I’ve therefore edited your question in the hopes of clarifying it. Please make sure my edit is in line with what you wanted to ask; if it isn’t, please don’t hesitate to remove anything I’ve added but which do not mean.

Answer (score 2):

PERLECHE
Pronunciation (US): Play (GB):  Play
 Dictionary entry overview: What does perleche mean?

• PERLECHE (noun)
  The noun PERLECHE has 1 sense:

1. a disorder of the lips marked by scaling and fissures at the corners of the mouth; caused by a deficiency of riboflavin
   **Familiarity information: PERLECHE used as a noun is very rare.**

**PERLECHE** (noun)
Sense 1 perleche 
Meaning: A disorder of the lips marked by scaling and fissures at the corners of the mouth; caused by a deficiency of riboflavin
Classified under:
Nouns denoting stable states of affairs
Synonyms:
cheilosis; perleche

Comment: I presume from the description that it looks similar to a "cold sore". Is that correct? if so it is probably called a cold sore. In contrast I believe a Canker sore, also called aphthous ulcers, show up as open sores on the inside of your mouth not outside.

Comment: What is the source of your quotation? Please provide attribution (and a link if possible)—otherwise, we could assume you simply made it up yourself.

Comment: @Brad This question has been very informative... I always had 'cold sores' as a child (which my mother treated with gentian violet, leading my teachers to continually ask if I had been chewing the end of a purple pen). I was vaguely puzzled that I never got them any more, since I clearly must *have* the virus. Due to this question I think I probably just had 'perleche' caused by the 'moist environment' generated by sucking my thumb...

Comment: I got the above quote from on line (Audio Dictionary) but maybe a better example is below from the BIOLOGY ONLINE DICTIONARY https://www.biology-online.org

Comment: Quote from on line (Audio Dictionary). Better example is below from the BIOLOGY ONLINE DICTIONARY https://www.biology-online.org  Perleche, Definition noun, A lesion characterized by cracks or splits at the labial commissure (the corner of the mouth) often bilaterally (on both sides) which may also be accompanied by scaling and cracks of the lips.
Supplement The lesions may bleed when the mouth is widely opened. The cause may be a fungal infection (e.g. Candida albicans infection) or vitamin B deficiency. Synonym(s):angular cheilitis cheilosis angular stomatitis commissural cheilit

Comment: @Brad Exactly! Cold sore is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Brad Please edit your post to include the complete attribution in accordance with our Help Center’s community guidelines on [How to reference material written by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Notice that you should use a `>` before each line you’re quoting [per our instructions on using markdown](https://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help).  Lastly, we expect you to write an answer consisting mainly of your words, not just one of someone else’s text copied from elsewhere. Answers without any original content provide little original value.

Comment: @tchrist OK will do. As for my answer consisting mainly of my words. I got ripped badly by an older member for doing that! they said I was making things up. So I deleted what I had posted.

Comment: Perhaps we should wait for clarification from the asker. I’ve discovered that their link was actually to *perlèche*, so I suspect this was not what they were after.  I’ve edited their post to try to make this clearer, but that's just me not them, so we should see what they say.

Comment: @tchrist - Based on comments above, It appears OP was looking for “cold sore”   I think Brad should update his answer to include it.

Comment: I would suggest that this answer doesn't even answer the original question, "I know there's this French word *Perleche* which is synonymous with Angular cheilitis. But Is there any common word for it in English?" All you have done is said that *perleche* is very rare in English. Also: this appears to be simple copypasta, without even acknowledging the source.

Comment: @Andrew Leach. Yes your correct, I did not link the source. Sorry I was/am new to this site. I will try to do better in the future, Regarding your comment "this answer doesn't even answer the original question" please note comment from the originator " Brad Exactly! Cold sore is what I was looking for. Thanks!" so I think this question could be closed.